# How to use Orchard CMS template module

Tags: orchardcms

There is a module in Orchard CMS that allows for editing templates within the dashboard, however it is unclear how to properly utilize the output.  What is the correct way to access a template in an MVC module controller, pass the template a model, and then render it within a View cshtml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can build any shape with the shapefactory:

```
public MyController(IShapeFactory shapeFactory) {
    Shape = shapeFactory;
}

public dynamic Shape { get; set; }

public ActionResult Index() {
    var someModel = new SomeModel();

    // You can build your shape here:
    var shape = Shape.TheTemplateShapeName(SomeData: someModel.SomeProperty);

    // or: Shape.New("TheTemplateShapeName").SomeData(someData); 
    // you can just chain on the dynamic shape

    var viewModel = Shape
        .ViewModel() // simple orchard method to build a viewmodel with chaining
        .MyShape(shape)
        .SomethingElse("Some string");

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then in your MyController/Index.cshtml:

```
<h1>@Model.SomethingElse</h1>
@Display(Model.MyShape)
```

Comment: Is ShapeFactory smart enough to find the template if it is in the database instead of in a View folder?  I am using the "Templates" module.  How would I use Shape Factory to say render a Page?

Comment: no it won't check the db, which module you mean with the "Templates" module?